# Submenu is disappearing on hover

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

My submenu is disappearing on hover.Please show me how to fix it.

```
#header {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.wp-toolbar #header{
    margin-top: 0;
}
#site-title, #site-description {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#theme-logo img {
    box-shadow: none;
}

/* =Navigation
*/
#top-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: 0;
}


#theme-top-menu {
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
#theme-top-menu .sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
}
.menu .current_page_item a, .menu .current-menu-item a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#theme-top-menu a {
    padding: 0 0.9em;
    border: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 80%;
}

#site-navigation{
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1140px;
    border-top: 1px solid #666666;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.fullwidth #site-navigation {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#site-navigation .theme-wrap {
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;

}
#theme-menu-main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#theme-menu-main > li {
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#theme-menu-main > li a {
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#theme-menu-main > li:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
#theme-menu-main > li > ul {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0.9em;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#theme-menu-main > li ul > li a {
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    font-weight: 100;
}
#theme-menu-main > li ul > li:last-child a{
    border: none;
}
#theme-menu-main > li > a span{
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

#theme-menu-main a {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.menu a:hover { background: none; }
```

Comment: It may have something to do with this line: `'#theme-menu-main > li:hover {'
    'background-color: transparent;'
    '}'`

Do you think you can place your code in jsfiddle or jsbin so we can play with it to try an resolve the problem. As is the question is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
ul li:hover ul {
display:block;
}
```